# Is 'program order' in Java allows reordering?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, jls

In one thread I have

```
write a = 0
write a = 1
write volatile flag = 1
```

In 2nd thread I have

```
read volatile flag // This always happens after I write volatile flag in thread 1
read a
```

Can a reordering happen so I see `read a` returning 0 in the 2nd thread?

If not, could someone, please, explain in detail why?

I'm asking becuase I'm puzzled by this definition from the JLS:

> Among all the inter-thread actions performed by each thread t, the
>   program order of t is a total order that reflects the order in which
>   these actions would be performed according to the intra-thread
>   semantics of t.

It looks as if allows for reordering in this situation?

Comment: can you post a code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reorder normal field around volatile field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919392/reorder-normal-field-around-volatile-field)

Comment: Repetition of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548547/can-a-reordering-happen-in-the-presence-of-a-volatile-variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a reordering happen so I see read a returning 0 in the 2nd thread?

No, not if your assertion is correct, "This always happens after I write volatile flag in thread 1"

The last update that thread 1 made to the variable `a` before it updated the volatile `flag` will be visible to thread 2 after thread 2 has read the volatile flag.

See section 3.1.4 of *Java Concurrency in Practice* by Brian Goetz for a more detailed explanation:  [http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)

---

But note!  It can be considered to be bad practice to depend on reads and writes of a volatile variable to synchronize *other* variables.  The problem is, the relationship between the volatile variable and the other variables may not be obvious to other programmers who work on the same code.

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#oldmm)

> The old memory model allowed for volatile writes to be reordered with nonvolatile reads and writes, which was not consistent with most developers intuitions about volatile and therefore caused confusion.

So such behavior is obsolete for now (since JSR-133 was introduced and took effect in Java 5.0).

And, secondly, as said [here](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/jmm-pragmatics/#_program_order)

> The actions linked together in program order do not preclude being "reordered"